# Python: Using a list to check items in a seperate list and if present then replace

Tags: python, list, replace

I am trying to check if items in list-one are in list-two and if so then replace the item in list-one in place (by appending a '_' to it).  The caveat is that the items in list-one have to remain in the original order.  I have figured out a way to do this with a nested for loop and and enumerate, but I was wondering if there is a more efficient/quicker method, possibly a list comprehension or map if appropriate? Thanks in advance.

The lists are:

```
 headers = ['Date', 'Temp', 'Descrip', 'ID', 'Lat', 'Long', 'FID']
 replace = ['Date', 'ID', 'FID']
```

The code I am using is:

```
 for rep in replace:
         for index, head in enumerate(headers):
                 if rep == head:
                         headers[ index ] = headers[ index ] + '_'
```

The answer should be:

```
 ['Date_', 'Temp', 'Descrip', 'ID_', 'Lat', 'Long', 'FID_']
```

Answer (score 7):

If you don't need to modify the list in place, you can use a list comprehension:

```
headers = [s + "_" if s in replace else s for s in headers]
```

If `replace` contains more than 3 items, you want to use a set instead of a list.  (If `headers` is a list, the test `s in headers` needs to iterate over the list, whereas if `headers` is a set, `s in headers` can be evaluated in constant time without iteration.)

Comment: Thanks. Yes this works for me.  I'm not too concerned about creating a new list, but it would be nice not to without having to use a long/explicit for loop.  I wish Python had a bang method similar to that of Ruby.  I do,however, have one question regarding your comment.  Why would I need to use set?  As I understand it 'set' gets rid of any redundancies.  Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Can we gain a significant extra performance if we replace `s + "_"` by `"".join([s, "_"])`?

Comment: @9monkeys: membership test is considerably faster for big sets than for big lists -- I added a comment to my answer.

Comment: @Selinap: No, this would be considerably slower, even when using a tuple instead of a list.  `str.join()` is only faster when you are joining more than two strings (and even then only when the strings are long or there are many strings).

Answer (score 2):

```
reps = set(replace)

for index, head in enumerate(headers):
    if head in reps:
        headers[index] += "_"
```

This will modify the list in place, as your original code did.  List comprehensions are more compact, but will create a new list.  I don't know whether that's a concern for you or not.

Answer (score 0):

List comprehensions is your best friend :).

```
>>> headers = ['Date', 'Temp', 'Descrip', 'ID', 'Lat', 'Long', 'FID']
>>> replace = ['Date', 'ID', 'FID']
>>> [i+"_" if i in replace else i for i in headers]
['Date_', 'Temp', 'Descrip', 'ID_', 'Lat', 'Long', 'FID_']
```

Of course you can change `i+"_"` to `"".join((i, "_"))` for performance reasons, I write it like this for readability.

Answer (score 0):

You can use one-liner - but note that it will create new list:

```
headers = ['Date', 'Temp', 'Descrip', 'ID', 'Lat', 'Long', 'FID']
rVals = ['Date', 'ID', 'FID']

res = [x if x not in rVals else x+'_' for x in headers]
```

OR:

```
map(lambda x: x if x not in rVals else x+'_', headers)
```

OR:

```
for x in (x for x in rVals if x in headers):
    headers.__setitem__(headers.index(x),x+'_')
```